# Wordpress; Sharing plugin only shared the blog main link

Tags: php, wordpress, sharing

I've a blog, and I used to show only a part from the blog posts (10 Blog posts) in the home, featured image, with the blog post title & around 100 word from the blog post it self . then (Continue reading)

in few days I decide to put a small facebook & twitter sharing links under thess blog post, not in the blog post it self but in home page but for the blog posts,

Sorry for my bad english, [the attached screenshot will explain what I want to say.!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJxC3.jpg)

But the main problem is the sharing buttons only shared the home page link and not the blog post links! I dont want to share the main blog link, I need each one of these links to share the blog post that related to it.

How I can fix that?

## Update

For the sharing buttons, I used this wordpress plugin: http://www.simplesharebuttons.com/wordpress

From the plugin settings you can choose where the sharing appears

I choose it all ( home page, posts, pages, archive)
but Its not working for the home page.

so what I did? I opened this file from the theme files:

content-standard.php

and I added this line in the file

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[ssba]"); ?>
```

ssba < is the shortcode for the plugin!

But its only share the home page link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the permanlink of the post http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink and use this URL on your share buttons

Comment: Thank you!, but can you give me more details where to use it exactly and how?

Comment: Can you paste the code of those share buttons? Update your question and paste it.

Comment: Added!, thank you for following up with me, please if you can help me this would be amazing :)

Comment: I never used this plugin, but I checked it up. You can pass a url to the shortcode.
Try this: 

`<?php echo do_shortcode("[ssba url=" . get_permalink() . "]"); ?>`

Comment: Its work for facebook! but for twitter its only show's the blog post link, can I add the title too in the tweet? and can I add via@ twitter handle?

Again! thank you very much!